# Docker how to commit images with name on repository and tag

Tags: docker

I've made the images of Ubuntu 14:04, on my local laptop.
Then I want to commit images,

I run this command to commit

```
 $ sudo Docker commit 2a1aef6a0547
```

However, there is no name on the repository and TAG

Like this, check images

```
 $ sudo docker images
```

The results

```
 REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
 <none>              <none>              87ab1f8aeb2f        12 minutes ago      5.34 GB
 ubuntu              14.04               e9ae3c220b23        2 weeks ago         187.9 MB
```

Name repository and tag is `<none>`

To be able to give a name, use syntax like??

Answer (score 19):

Check the [docker commit usage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) parameters:

```
Usage: docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

In fact, the example presented there shows how to do this:

```
$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  SvenDowideit/testimage:version3
f5283438590d

$ docker images    
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID                  CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
SvenDowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d
```

Depending on what you are trying to do though - you may wish to [start building images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerimages/) from a(n) (existing) `Dockerfile` instead.

Comment: error sir, iam running
$ sudo docker commit 87ab1f8aeb2f ubuntu_tes:14.04
Error response from daemon: no such id: 87ab1f8aeb2f

Comment: You're using the wrong ID - from *images*. You're supposed to use the `CONTAINER ID` from `docker ps -a`.

Answer (score 5):

Running this syntax

```
$ sudo docker tag 87ab1f8aeb2f name_your_images:latest
```

Example

```
$ sudo docker tag 87ab1f8aeb2f ubuntu_test:14.04
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question following is the syntax:

```
docker commit -a "Author Name" -m "Commit message" container-id/container-name new-image-name
```

where `-a` & `-m` are optional and `/` denotes an *or* condition so it is container id *or* container name.

example for the same is:

```
docker commit -a "Some Name Here" -m "Simple nginx hosted on 8080" hello-nginx-container hello-nginx-yj
```

Now to be able to push this image to docker hub the new-image-name must be prefixed with `YOUR_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/`.

I have created an [example Docker project](https://github.com/yogesh-jog/Getting_Started_With_Docker/tree/master/nginx), it includes more details about this exact same question [in the documentation](https://github.com/yogesh-jog/Getting_Started_With_Docker/blob/master/nginx/readme.md#docker-tag-while-commit).

All the links mentioned above are my own github repo links.